# How to add user in Mongo admin database from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to add a super user to `admin` database from MongoDB using NodeJS. My first try is this:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var db = new Db('admin', new Server('locahost', 27017));

// Establish connection to db
db.open(function(err, db) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }

    console.log("Opened database");

    // Add a user to the database
    db.addUser('superuser', '1234', {
        roles: [
            "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
            "clusterAdmin",
            "readWriteAnyDatabase"
        ]   
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log("Added.");
    });
});
```

When running the script I got this error:

> `[Error: failed to connect to [locahost:27017]]`

And before this:

```
========================================================================================
=  Please ensure that you set the default write concern for the database by setting    =
=   one of the options                                                                 =
=                                                                                      =
=     w: (value of > -1 or the string 'majority'), where < 1 means                     =
=        no write acknowledgement                                                       =
=     journal: true/false, wait for flush to journal before acknowledgement             =
=     fsync: true/false, wait for flush to file system before acknowledgement           =
=                                                                                      =
=  For backward compatibility safe is still supported and                              =
=   allows values of [true | false | {j:true} | {w:n, wtimeout:n} | {fsync:true}]      =
=   the default value is false which means the driver receives does not                =
=   return the information of the success/error of the insert/update/remove            =
=                                                                                      =
=   ex: new Db(new Server('localhost', 27017), {safe:false})                           =
=                                                                                      =
=   http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command                           =
=                                                                                      =
=  The default of no acknowledgement will change in the very near future                =
=                                                                                      =
=  This message will disappear when the default safe is set on the driver Db           =
========================================================================================
```

How can I fix the script to add the user `superuser` with password `1234` to `admin` database from MongoDB?

Comment: Administrative operations like adding an admin should rather be done through the mongo shell, not through a program.

Comment: @Philipp So, I guess the best alternative would be to run shell commands from Nodejs side... Right?

Comment: When your error is `[Error: failed to connect to [locahost:27017]]` it likely means that the problem occurs **long before** you try to create a new user. So when you wonder how to create a user, you are searching in the wrong direction.

Comment: forget node.js for a moment and use the `mongo` command line utility to connect to your database.

Comment: @Philipp It cannot open `admin` database, I guess.

Comment: `[Error: failed to connect to [locahost:27017]]` means, your mongod deamon is not running. Start the mongo service first via `sudo mongod start`

Comment: @Sriharsha The mongod daemon **is** running...

Comment: `new Server('locahost', 27017)`, Do you see any problem here? Look closely! **Typo** in localhost name

Comment: @Sriharsha Good point! Look in the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html). Same typo. ;-)

Comment: @イオニカビザウ Maybe they do have a database server named `locahost` on their LAN :)

Comment: Why do I always see an 'l' in "locahost"? "locahost".indexOf('l') == -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line:

```
 var db = new Db('admin', new Server('locahost', 27017));
```

You made a typo. What you mean is `localhost`.